# How to make endless While loop for checking a state?

Tags: python

```
while pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)) != None:
    playsound('click.mp3')
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)) == None:
        continue
```

pyautogui takes a screenshot and checks whether my image is in certain region or not, I want it to keep repeating

```
playsound('click.mp3')
```

when the image is visible, but when its not I want it to keep checking (repeating **pyautogui.locateOnScreen**) if the image is visible again . So far my code ends when I hide the image, I dont know how to keep it as "Standby".
Also, Im having a very hard time understanding the **continue** function, does it go back and read **while** again and again?

**EDIT**
I also tried this

```
while pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)) is not None:
    playsound('click.mp3')
else:
    continue
```

Comment: Not helping with your question, but note that [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) states that `Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.`

Comment: `continue` stops the current iteration step and continues with the next. In case of a `while` loop it goes up to the `while` and evaluates the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two different states:

```py
while True:

    while pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)):
        playsound('click.mp3')
    
    while not pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)):
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I have another question if you can answer, i want this endless loop to break with a keyboard combination, ive already written `Try: .... except KeyboardInterrupt: ..... break` but it returns `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`

Comment: The try/except will just work without the ‘break’.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `continue` isn't necessary since `continue` skips the rest of the loop body, then starts again at the top after checking the condition. There isn't anything else in the loop to skip though, so your code would be better written as:

```
while pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)) is not None:
    playsound('click.mp3')
```

Which loops until the condition is false, and the condition will only be false when the image can't be found. If you want to loop forever, use `while True`, and only play the sound when the image is found:

```
while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('white4x4.png', region = (200,200,4,4)) is not None:
        playsound('click.mp3')
```